# Copy/Paste from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to create a button that opens a dialogue box for a user to select a file which then copies data from that selected file into the current workbook.  I am able to get the dialogue box to open and select a file but I get an error stating the "PastSpecial method of Range class Failed".  Additionally I am trying to get this to paste to an already existing list but I haven't made it that for to figure out.  Anyone know how I can fix this error and add to an existing list?

```
Sub Get_Data_From_File()
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim OpenBook As Workbook
     
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A4:R1000").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3).Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPastValues
        OpenBook.Close False
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3).Range("A2:R998").Value = OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A4:R1000").Value`

Comment: The response above is the best solution, but you should know that you did not spell `xlPasteValues` correctly

Comment: Prefect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Copy Range From Another Workbook

**Common Steps**

- Open Source Workbook (`Openbook`).
- Define (create a reference to) Source Range (`srg`).
- Define (create a reference to) Destination First Cell (`dCell`).
- Use `Resize` to copy by assignment:

  ```
  dCell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count).Value = srg.Value
  ```
- Close Source Workbook (`Openbook`).

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Get_Data_From_File()
     
    ' Pick Source File.
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", _
        FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ' Open Source Workbook (File).
        Dim OpenBook As Workbook: Set OpenBook = Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        ' Define Source Range.
        Dim srg As Range: Set srg = OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A4:R1000")
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Range("A2")
            ' Define Destination First (available) Cell.
            Dim dCell As Range
            Set dCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
                .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
            If dCell Is Nothing Then
                Set dCell = .Offset ' "A2" is the first available cell.
            Else
                Set dCell = dCell.Offset(1)
            End If
            ' Copy by assignement.
            dCell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count).Value = srg.Value
            '.Worksheet.Parent.Save ' Save Destination Workbook.
        End With
        ' Close Destination Workbook.
        OpenBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        'MsgBox "Range copied."
    Else
        'MsgBox "Cancelled."
    End If
    
End Sub
```